# search text lazily

Tags: regex

I'd like to search text starting with **noun** or **adj** or **adv** until it meets with **<**. **noun**,  **adj**, and **adv** should not appear again between them and **<**. I expected this regex would work, but it failed. How can I make this work?

```
(noun|adj|adv)[^\1]+?<
```

Comment: Please provide limit examples of what should/shouldn't you get.

Comment: For debugging your regexp try this (fabulous) site: http://myregexp.com

Answer (score 0):

`[...]` bracket syntax will search for individual characters only.

Here you need to use a negative assertion: `((?!\1).)+` could do it. Provided your regexp syntax is perl/ecmascript compatible.

```
(noun|adj|adv)((?!\1).)+<
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution are semi-right, but none of them got it right. Robert got it completely wrong. @Benoit was closer to being right, but still wrong. Here's why: http://regex101.com/r/qI7hA6 -- the engine will merely match in another position where the lookahead does not fail. You also set unnecessary backreferences. On top of that, you still allow noun/adj/adv in the text.

Here is a better solution: http://regex101.com/r/nL8lL7

`/^|\G(?:noun|adj|adv)((?:(?!noun|adj|adv).)+)</gm`

I hope this works. If it is not what you're looking for, please clarify and I'll adjust the expression accordingly.

Good luck.

Comment: In your own testcase `noun with adj and adv with other text and <html>`it doesn't match anything. Whereas Benoits solution does. Backtracking is not necessary, on that one I agree. Further the author explicitly excluded the fact you mentioned: "noun, adj, and adv should not appear again between them and <"

Comment: @user1610952: If the solution is what you're looking for, please accept it. @Tobias N. Sasse: Yes, none of the words should appear again. So if it matches `adj`, there may not be `adj`, `noun` or `adv` in the text. Mine passes this test, Benitos does not. At least that is how I understood the task at hand.